# Splitting field of two distinct elements and polynomials

Tags: field-theory

If two elements with distinct minimal polynomials generate the same extension field are the splitting fields of the two minimal polynomials equal?
If this is not true, show me the example

Comment: Please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tried, where you are stuck.

Comment: Someone just posted this question a few days ago, but it seems to have been deleted. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2349203/help-me-this-question-is-crazy-field-theory

Comment: Added context can also relate to what makes the problem interesting, what motivates the problem, or what aspects of the solution the OP has already worked out for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If $K(\alpha)$ is a simple field extension and $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, then the splitting field of $f$ is just the normal closure of $K(\alpha)$. Thus if two elements generate the same field extension, the splitting fields of their minimal polynomials are the same.

Comment: what is mean of normal clousure? Is this not same conception of splitting field?

Comment: @chosangsoo:  This [previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313300/question-on-the-normal-closure-of-a-field-extension) explains the construction of the normal closure.